# Public free web services for testing soap client

Tags: python, web-services, soap, soappy, zsi

Are there any publicly available [SOAP 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_(protocol))/[WSDL 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) compliant free web services for testing a Python based soap client library (e.g. [Zolera SOAP Infrastructure](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/))?

So far, it appears to me that [Google Web API](http://www.google.com/apis/) may be the only option.

Otherwise, how can one test a [SOAP 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_(protocol)) compliant client library?

Comment: Hey can i get any sample url of POST type web serivce ?

Comment: This site have some working soap web services [https://jansipke.nl/examples-of-public-soap-web-services/](https://jansipke.nl/examples-of-public-soap-web-services/)

Comment: As of 2018: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx Very simple SOAP Calculator. The WSDL: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is a bunch on here:

http://www.webservicex.net/WS/wscatlist.aspx

Just google for "Free WebService" or "Open WebService" and you'll find tons of open SOAP endpoints.

Remember, you can get a WSDL from any ASMX endpoint by adding ?WSDL to the url.

Comment: lol I google "Free WerbService" and it took me here.. I guess that will eventually will throw StackOverflowException :P

Comment: This is no longer working.

Comment: Still works. May be down intermittently.

Comment: Hey can i get any sample url of POST type web serivce ?

Comment: Most of the services I tested are not operational (Out of disk space).

Comment: No longer working.

Comment: link is not wirking

Comment: http://free-web-services.com/, if you are interested in SOAP ws http://soapclient.com/newsservice.html

Comment: so i guess this is dead technology

Comment: Broken link needed to update

Comment: http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl this website has many working SOAP services that you can test.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş it's broken too. :(

Comment: It was alive a week ago, sorry :/

Comment: Try [ProgrammableWeb](https://www.programmableweb.com) - not all are free, but as of June 2018, they've got a number of sites with interesting information.

Comment: This works: http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/free-restful-web-services-to-consume-and-test.htm

Comment: Lates and greatest OMB -> free web service to obtain movie information: https://any-api.com/omdbapi_com/omdbapi_com/docs/API_Description

Comment: This is a collection of different SOAP APIs that are completley public and do not require any authentication, making it easier for consumers to play with and understand what APIs are all about by seeing the many different ways in which APIs can be used.

 [Public SOAP APIs - Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/Szf26WHn#4ba276a7-b12c-4943-ae23-c6031cc48248)

Comment: The link Yurii Holslkyi posted is working to date.