# Do you know of any free SOAP webservices (for tutorial purpose)

Tags: soap, webservice-client

Only for tutorial purpose, I would like to try to use a free SOAP web services available.

Which ones come to your mind ?

The business implied behind is not important/relevant: Only the ease of access (free access), and simplicity of the service contract.

Any indication welcome !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public free web services for testing soap client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311654/public-free-web-services-for-testing-soap-client)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can look at this post

[Public free web services for testing soap client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311654/public-free-web-services-for-testing-soap-client)

Comment: A link to a link which ultimately shows a server error. Wow!

Comment: This site have some working soap web services [https://jansipke.nl/examples-of-public-soap-web-services/](https://jansipke.nl/examples-of-public-soap-web-services/)

Comment: This is a collection of different SOAP APIs that are completley public and do not require any authentication, making it easier for consumers to play with and understand what APIs are all about by seeing the many different ways in which APIs can be used.

 [Public SOAP APIs - Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/Szf26WHn#4ba276a7-b12c-4943-ae23-c6031cc48248)
Remember, you can get a WSDL from any ASMX endpoint by adding `?wsdl` to the url.

Answer (score 0):

One I have used is http://www.service-repository.com/

Comment: This link doesn't work: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: still doesn't work 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: @Thayz No, now, your link doesn't work either.

Comment: @LubošStaráček - sorry, I know its too late. I just noticed your comment. I just checked again and it seems working...

Comment: @Thayz You're right. It seems working. It was maybe some temporary outage or something.