# Need a sample webserivce which publish data for testing .

Tags: web-services, service, web, wsdl, informatica-powercenter

I am doing a POC for a tool called informatica functionality if that can be used to read the data from a webservice which publish data. It will be like there is a  external data provided which is ready to publish data over webservice and I have to use the adapter of this toll to read that data and create a flat flile out of it. There will be no input provided from our side(other than autentication.). Are there any such web services available which can be sued for that /

Comment: **(1)** Make the question more general - what you need is a publicly available Web service. The fact that you are going to consume in a PowerCenter mapping is not relevant. **(2)** Check what type of Web service is suitable for you - SOAP, REST or any type will do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public free web services for testing soap client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311654/public-free-web-services-for-testing-soap-client)

Answer (score 0):

You can look an [`UDDI`](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=uddi-spec) of some available web services you can use, and also few companies has web services for test purpose like [`Publicly Available Web Services`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780596156091/getting-started/sect-publicavailablesvcs)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, reading webservice data is fragile using Informatica and it depends on the type of Webservice how well it works.
Testing works best, if you have at least some wsdl file, that you can feed into SoapUI. With the pro-Version you can even use that wsdl File to provide a dummy Webservice which you can then read data using Informatica.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some webservices you can try: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_use.asp